# Laravel Operators AND / && - How to Use Them?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use `AND` as well as `&&` in this code block:

```
public function show($id)
{

    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
    $share = Share::where('sbj_id', $id)->first();

    if ($share->sbj_id == $id && $share->email == $userEmail )  {

        $items = Item::where('project_id', $id)
        ->orderBy("created_at", "desc")
        ->groupBy('label_name')
        ->get();

        $sbj = Sbj::find($id);
        $allSbj = Sbj::where('user_id', $user)->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->get();
        $labels = Label::all();
        $pages = Page::where('project_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        $people = Friend::where('sbj_id', $id)->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->get();
        $myPeeps = Contact::where('my_id', $user)->get();

        return View::make('sbjs.show', compact('sbj', 'pages', 'labels', 'people', 'myPeeps', 'allSbj', 'items'));

    } else {

        return Redirect::action ('SbjsController@index');
    }


}
```

However, I am looking online to see if `&&` or `AND` is supported in Lavavel in this context but no success. My app is taking the user to the `ELSE` action.

Any ideas?

Comment: && and AND are part of PHP itself, not just Laravel... I would check that the values of $userEmail and $share->email are what you expect...

Answer (score 0):

I just added the Eloquent statement to the IF conditional and it worked fine...not sure why it was not evaluating.